# Docusign CreateEnvelop does not return

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

When I try and send an envelop through email (docusign test sandbox), my test application sends the envelop, yet api call is not returned. I enabled clientUserId so I can get the URL for redirecting end user, unable to get to this stage as CreateEnvelope calls is never returned.

What is strange is that the same app works fine through my local machine, when integrating it in the server where my test app is hosted, it does not return and shows no error.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated!

```
AccountID = API Account ID 
IntegerationID = IntegerationID 
signerClientId = random number I assigned for testing purposes,
passed to both MakeEnvelope and MakeRecipientViewRequest
```

I use JWT to get accessToken without the need to login to DocuSign
I handled the consent on my account outside the app (one time consent approved)

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, signerClientId);
 var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
 List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
 scopes.Add("signature impersonation");
      

 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privateKeyStr);

  string accessToken = (docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(IntegerationId, userId, oauthBasePath, bytes, 3600, scopes)).access_token;

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envelope); //this never returns 
string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;
```

Expecting a envelopID to be returned

Using .net framework 4.7.2 docusign sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having the same issue. After banging my head against a brick wall for half a day, I eventually found this: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client/issues/399.

Updating the SDK to 6.4.1 solved the problem.

Comment: Right, SDK 6.4.1 fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume it might be a network issue. Please check whether your test environment (firewall, proxy, load balancer) blocks DocuSign packets or routes the packets to the wrong place.

FYI, you should whitelist the DocuSign domains and its subdomains to communicate with DocuSign:

*.docusign.com

*.docusign.net

Answer (score 0):

If your app works fine on your local machine but not on your server, then the problem is on your server.

Discuss with your server administrators.

Also, use [DocuSign request logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) to see the log when you use your local machine and when you use your server. If DocuSign shows no request from your server then, again, that would point to a networking/firewall issue in your server.

Comment: I enabled the logging and no request is showing from my server. However, when using HTTP request it works fine and I get back data from DocuSign , but SDK does not.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue with the sdk. Open a ticket with developer support if you can't crack the issue